# Environment for specific application

Tags: linux, environment-variables

Is it possible to specify environment variables for a given application only? So that environment variables are set automatically when the application starts ('VAR=VALUE myapp' is not what I want).

The actual problem is, I want wine to always start with a specific LC_ALL setting, but don't want to change LC_ALL globally. There're lots of places that could start wine (terminal, gnome file associations, menu shortcuts), and manually setting LC_ALL in all of these seems too tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is to change your PATH so that, e.g., `/usr/local/bin` comes first and then create a `/usr/local/bin/wine` like so:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 export FOO=bar

 /usr/local/bin/wine "$@"
```

I don't know how these "gnome file associations" and "menu shortcuts" work. If they hardcode the full path rather than relying on `$PATH` this soln won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it didn't come up to me. Will give it a try.

Comment: Actually, Ubuntu has /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin by default, just needed to put a script there. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Rename the main wine binary from `wine` to `wine.real`.  Create a script in place of the wine binary that looks something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
FOO=bar
export foo
wine.real $* &
```

Comment: Tried this, but the script gets overwritten with each wine update. So I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make an alias so you don't need to change something that your software manager manages. E.g., in your ~/.bash_profile

```
 alias wine='FOO=bar; \wine'
```

The `\` prevents supresses alias expansion to prevent infinite recursion.

Edit: this solution won't work in all the situations you mention.